# How to combine a dictionary and list by key

Tags: c#, json, list, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like this:

```
Dictionary<String, String> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>{
  { "dog", "DOG" },
  { "cat", "CAT" },
  ...continued
};
```

and I want to extract the Id value from a list that has a matching value like below:

```
List<Animal> records = new List<Animal>{
  { Id: "1", Name: "DOG" },
  { Id: "2", Name: "CAT" }
  ...continued
}
```

I need to output a dictionary that looks like this:

```
Dictionary<String, String> newDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
  { "dog": "1" },
  { "cat": "2 }
  ...continued
}
```

Is there a simple LINQ solution to this?

Comment: You are not using dictionary. Thats 'var'.

Comment: I've edited it with the correct types now

Comment: What have you tried to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `JOIN` to get matching records from dictionary and list like this:

```
var query = from d in dictionary
        join r in records
        on d.Value equals r.Name
        select new { Id=r.Id, Name=d.Key };

var newDictionary = query.ToDictionary(d => d.Name, d => d.Id);
```